# $x(t)$ is a solution of the equation $x′ = f(t,x)$ such that $x(0) \neq 0$, show that $x(t) \neq 0,~ \forall t ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider the following problem.

Let $f(t,x) ∈ C(\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ and satisfy a local Lipschitz condition in $x$. Assume $f(t,0) = 0$. If $x(t)$ is a solution of the equation $x′ = f(t,x)$ such that $x(0) \neq 0$, show that $x(t) \neq 0$ for any $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I would appreciate any tips or hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there is $t_0 \ne 0$ such that $x(t_0)=0.$ Then $x$ is a solution of the IVP

$$(*) \quad x'(t)=f(t,x(t), \quad x(t_0)=0.$$

Now set $z(t)=0$ for $t \in \mathbb R$. Since $f(t,0) = 0$ for all $t$, the function $z$ is also a solution of $(*)$.

But $f$ is local Lipschitz condition in $x$, hence, by Picard-Lindelöf, $(*)$ has a unique solution. This gives $z=x$, hence $z(0)=x(0) \ne 0$, a contradiction.